# Blockchain Wallet

Tags: mining-pools

I had a gentleman contact me about mining using his miner through his so called company. If the company created the wallet using my email and then I receive an email to verify the wallet has been made but did not provide my user id or password can the company still access my wallet at any time without this information

Comment: Well known scam. Never give anyone access to your wallet.

Answer (score 2):

**This 100% sounds like a scam to me.** Consider that wallet compromised, do not send any BTC to it. Create a new wallet for any future bitcoin transactions you do.

If the 'company' had access at any point to your blockchain.info wallet, they will have been able to copy down the seed phrase that generates all keypairs used by the wallet. With that seed phrase, they can re-create your wallet using other software, so a password/login will not stop them at all. Even if you change your password, the seed phrase will remain the same, and they will be able to steal your bitcoin.