# My Bitcoin was transferred to someone’s address from my blockchain wallet!

Tags: blockchain

Ok I have done research on my situation and this is what I have found. On 1/17/2021 I tried to login to my blockchain wallet and the captcha was glitching. It asked like 10 times! So I sent blockchain an email at 2:49pm what was going on. The following day I logged in and it says my Bitcoin was transferred to a wallet in 2 separate transactions @ 2:50pm 1/17/2021! What the hell! Can someone please help me understand how someone could have gotten into my blockchain wallet? I have 2 factor authentication on and everything! It also sends an email if an unfamiliar up address is used to try and login. I then have to go in to authorize it is me before it will allow me in. I am very confused can someone help me understand how I can learn this process better or track down where this wallet is? I have sent a message to blockchain and they are no help at all! Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovery from theft - Tracing money to exchanges](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98929/recovery-from-theft-tracing-money-to-exchanges)

Comment: I did a search for "blockchain.com" on reddit and there were similar user complaints and 2FA was also mentioned. Maybe read those conversations for what they did