# Scammed by Bitcoin Recovery Expert

Tags: blockchain, wallet

We were initially scammed for 1000.00 through blockchain. So then we did some research online about fraud recovery experts. We came across a site called stallionedge.tech and their clients had rave reviews about how long it took to get their money in a matter of days, so we were able to get in touch with them. We called the phone number listed on their website and it was disconnected. They said that they can only contact us, that is why it is disconnected when somebody tries to call them. So we thought okay. They communicated with us back and forth via email. So when it came time to pay them to help, I was told to download whatsapp and that a withdrawal specialist would contact me. The withdrawal specialist, Christopher, contacted me. We initially had to pay 250.00 for services rendered. Well, then he said that we needed to deposit 460.00 to show activity on our blockchain account, so we reluctantly did. It disappeared in a matter of minutes. They said that there was a glitch and that they would help figure it out. That we were his top priority and that they deal with clients like us on a daily basis. Well, a couple of days later, we were asked to deposit 460.00 more and they would help us get the previous 460.00 back along with over 2000.00 that was taken from our blockchain account. It supposedly accrued up to over 2000.00. We received a screenshot of the transaction that they claimed was waiting to be sent to us. It looked legitimate. Well, it wound up disappearing in a matter of minutes, too. The thing is, is that he is still communicating with us via the whatsapp. I have all the texts, emails and screenshots as proof if you need those. Please help. I don't know if there is a way to recover the money that we paid, but their website needs shut down and the people need punished that have taken advantage of us. I am assuming this is a scam, but if it is a legitimate company, they are taking advantage of me. He says that you can contact him. We have his contact info if you need it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91943/how-do-i-recover-from-a-cryptocurrency-scam). Also see how to look for signs a business is not honest in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866. The domain Stallionedge.tech was only registered a few weeks ago - it looks like a throwaway domain and website, soon they'll probably close it and open some new ones with similar information and fake reviews.

Comment: What do you suggest we do? Is there any way we can possibly get our money back?

Comment: 1) Report the fraud to your local police. 2) No, the money is gone and you will never get it back. I suggest learning what you can from the experience, putting it all behind you and moving on with your life.

Comment: I reported it already. What about the person that contacted me on whatsapp? What can I do about them?

Comment: Report them to WhatsApp? It's probably a throwaway account, faked.