# I was withdrawing my bitcoins and told to contact these to these addresses am I being scammed

Tags: fraud

bitcoin:bc1qesx9ft0kjv43eagnhv0tf063pzryhec3eww3v6?amount=0.00383635 I was contacted until that it was time to withdraw my bitcoins and was told to send them to these addresses, but nothings happened. Am I being scammed?

Comment: Who contacted you? Where did that address come from?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I being scammed?

Yes.

Bitcoin was designed as digital cash that you can keep hold of in your own personal electronic wallet on your own personal electronic gadget (pc, phone etc) that no one else has any access to or control over.

You can however choose to give your electronic cash to someone else to look after for you, a custodian. Typically these are businesses that describe themselves as exchanges but which act like a bank in that they keep your cash in an account from which you can withdraw your cash.

In the case of a genuine Bitcoin exchange (there are also many fake ones) you typically withdraw cash by downloading [a Bitcoin wallet app](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) to your phone or PC, click the "receive money" button to get a new address in your own wallet and give that address to the exchange when it asks where you want to withdraw money to.

If you give the exchange an address created by someone else, that person is scamming you and tricking you into giving your money to them. I believe this is very clearly deceitful and that you should not trust anyone who asks you to do anything like this.

If you want to convert your digital cash into cash in a traditional currency like US dollars, Euros, etc. Some exchanges can do this for you. Again you need to be extremely careful when you choose a business to do the exchange for you. There are many tricksters and fake exchanges set up by criminals.

See

- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866)

---

The address you mentioned can be examined at any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer).

For example, [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1qesx9ft0kjv43eagnhv0tf063pzryhec3eww3v6) says that as of 2022-01-03 11:24 UTC that address has no money (a zero "balance") and was involved in no historical transactions.

My advice is:

- Dont send any money to that address.
- Block all contact from the person who gave you that address.