# Help with bitcoin transfer to my ewallet

Tags: fraud, withdrawal

**Please Help..**
I have been trying to withdraw my bitcoin off a website called mirminingpro.top I do everything it tells me but then at the end when I exchange coin it does nothing and I have a ewallet but I can't seem to figure it out..I tried cash app an it said I don't have enough to exchange but the site says  have 1.349223 bitcoins so I am so confused

Answer (score 1):

> **I have been trying to withdraw my bitcoin off a website called mirminingpro.top**

That website is almost certainly a scam. The domain was only registered a few days ago

> ```
> WHOIS search results
> Domain Name: mirminingpro.top
> Registry Domain ID: D20230401G10001G_98928793-top
> Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.nicenic.net
> Registrar URL: http://www.nicenic.net
> Updated Date: 2023-04-01T09:20:30Z
> Creation Date: 2023-04-01T09:20:30Z
> ```

I am distrustful of any website that offers to mine Bitcoin for you. There's no honest business model that supports that kind of proposition.

In short I believe you are the victim of a confidence trickster, a conman, a criminal intent on deceiving you in order to steal money using fraud.

There is no realistic way to get back any money you have paid, any "earnings" or "gains" etc shown on the website are almost certainly fake. Continued contact can only lead to loss. Anyone offering to help recover money is almost certainly only trying to exploit you further.

---

> **I am so confused**

It seems a standard technique of conmen is to deliberately confuse their victims and to panic them, for example by telling them that everything will be lost if they don't act quickly as the conman instructs. They want to overcome your rational decision making process and make you act in haste, in panic, without thinking things through.

I believe the best thing to do is to accept you will never get any money out of that site, discard any apps or accounts associated with this. Cease all contact with anyone recommending or associated with the site, put this incident behind you  and move on with your life.

---

- [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)
- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866)

Comment: Thank you so very much. I really appreciate your help I thought something was wrong I mean I am no expert but I can do some as simple as a tranfer. I really thank you an appreciate your time an help.