# Bitcoin Received But Then Sent

Tags: sending, receiving

I received Bitcoin to my wallet but it looks like that was the sent out to someone else.  How could that be?

The transaction number for the received coin on explorer shows:

5d4f4ab8b95c7efe6ada33d99fac018727f103a48f0b93dfe7f42a9f6fc08863

Then there is a "Sent" activity with the transaction:

e8cdcacf2f584278e3d1266e4a321241beb4c77372a9901969b12049ffb0c3c6

Did my Bitcoin get automatically sent from my account after receiving it because I never saw where it was in my wallet.  It's only been 30 hours.

Yes I am a total moron, but I was forced into this platform by an enterprise.  Otherwise I would avoid it because I don't understand it.
And my mom just died so I'm dealing with that and losing my job, so if some Samaritan could answer this so I'm less ignorant,I would be most appreciative. The first link is to the transaction on explorer when I received it and the second is for the sent transaction

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/5d4f4ab8b95c7efe6ada33d99fac018727f103a48f0b93dfe7f42a9f6fc08863/

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/e8cdcacf2f584278e3d1266e4a321241beb4c77372a9901969b12049ffb0c3c6/

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information in your question to be certain but one common reason that money unexpectedly leaves a wallet is theft. It means someone else has the private keys for the receiving address in the first transaction.

This might be because you had an online friend or helper who guided you through the choice of wallet software and the initial process. Perhaps this online friend was not your friend and deliberately deceived you in order to steal money from you.

It might be because you downloaded software that was not the genuine software but a maliciously altered copy. This happened to many Electrum wallet users some years ago. Thieves made malicious use of a feature in the software to trick people into "updating" the software by downloading a malicious version from a website run by the thieves.

It might be because the device you use to hold your wallet software is something you also use for other purposes and you at some time downloaded some compromised software or software that opened a security loophole that has been exploited by thieves.

Some red flags:

> I was forced into this platform by an enterprise.

Being forced into some unfamiliar process is a very common thread in incidences of deception and theft.

The word platform suggests something other than a normal non-custodial wallet.

Bitcoin was designed specifically so that one party could pay a second party without ever needing the services of any trusted third party - without any sort of business service acting as a trusted intermediary. When you use a business to hold your money you are giving up one of the main benefits of Bitcoin as intended by its creator.

> account

The pattern of transactions suggests a normal non-custodial (aka self-custodial) wallet but the use of the word account suggests some sort of online business service - a custodial arrangement of some sort.

It is common that criminals try to confuse and panic their victims and this often leads to seemingly contradictory and confusing descriptions of the events.

---

Some other questions here whose answers may be helpful:

- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866)
- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)
- [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)

Comment: It won't let me upload the screen caps which are in my coin wallet which I imported the Bitcoin wallet into

Comment: Can I send them to you and you decipher them for me? I'm totally lost

Comment: Please edit any additional information or images into your question. With this kind of event it is of paramount importance that any help is given in public so that misinformation can be pointed out by other readers. Private messaging is a tool loved by confidence tricksters and especially by those pretending to be recovery agents. Beware.

Comment: Well I'm clearly not smart enough to manage that. I can't even imagine how the funds received were instantly sent elsewhere without me entering the information

Answer (score 0):

That's what I get for not using a more established platform's app.

I have switched to another and everything is coming in as it should. I will count the $300 as tuition at the school of hard knocks