# Reflecting Fee?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm currently dealing with a case where I am asked to pay a Bitcoin reflecting fee in order to receive my withdrawl amount to my cashapp/bitcoin wallet. It is not currently showing anything pending on my blockchain wallet. The fee they are wanting me to pay is 1100 for 80,669 withdrawl from CrptPay Finech Agency out of the Netherlands, have you heard of this agency? Whether it is legit or not? I have been receiving I believe fake scam calls and messages from Bitcoin and need to know if this is real or scam. I have received no money in the 5k fees I have paid.

Comment: See also [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866) - Any upfront fees for withdrawing money are a certain sign of a scam.