# Crypto falling into the crypto universe due to blockchain break

Tags: blockchain, wallet

A trading entity processed a withdrawal and sent the supposed USDT to my wallet address. However the USDT I was expecting never arrive in my wallet. Upon checking, the trading platform support claimed "your withdrawal has been completed, the reason it didn't arrive is that you got a blockchain break and your withdrawal fell in the crypto universe." Even suggesting "This requires hiring a professional tech team to help you string the secret key together so that you can complete the withdrawal."
What do I do and how do I go about this to recover my funds?

Comment: USDT is not Bitcoin (so off-topic here) but see [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)