# Someon offered me btc mine trough his mining device

Tags: security, mining-hardware, fraud, wallet-security

Someone from the social network offered me a btc mine through his mining device. He asked me for an email address so he could create a mining wallet address for me. I gave it to him. I don't know what he did, but very soon after that I received an email from Blockchain informing me that my wallet address had been created and that I could connect it directly to the mining stream.
After this I should deposit a certain amount of btc to this wallet address, which is now, supposedly connected to this gentleman’s mining device.
is this a scam attack or ..

Comment: Seem like a scam yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Someone else created a wallet for me to use. Is this a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88910/someone-else-created-a-wallet-for-me-to-use-is-this-a-scam)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a scam. Don't send them anything.