Is this a possible fraud with bitcoin wallet
how do I find out if I have a bitcoin wallet. I have been contacted by a company who say I have a wallet but I did not buy bitcoin

Does one of these answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/88910/5406

This description matches a common scam. If you respond, the criminals behind it will gain your confidence and trick you into paying some seemingly plausible but fake fees.
